# Accordion.accordion('active', variable) not working

Tags: jquery

Setting accordion.accordion('active', variable) is not working in jquery

I tried

```
 if ($.trim(selectedaccordianId) != "") {
        $("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", selectedaccordianId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might help someone having the same issue, so I am posting this. Use parseInt(variable) name when trying to activate accordion tab using variable

```
$("#accordion").accordion("option", "active", parseInt(selectedaccordianId));
```